# DependentUpon not working for RESX files on .NET Core

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-core, resx, csproj

I am facing a small problem, I am trying to collapse inside Solution Explorer all localizable RESX files insde it own main RESX file, I have tried different approaches but no one seems to work, the code I have right now inside CSPROJ is the follwing:

```
<ItemGroup>
<Compile Update="Resources\ExceptionResources.Designer.cs">
  <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
  <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
  <DependentUpon>ExceptionResources.resx</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
<Compile Update="Resources\ExceptionResources.es-ES.resx">
  <DependentUpon>ExceptionResources.resx</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
<EmbeddedResource Update="Resources\ExceptionResources.resx">
  <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
  <LastGenOutput>ExceptionResources.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
</EmbeddedResource>
<EmbeddedResource Update="Resources\ExceptionResources.es-ES.resx">
  <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
  <LastGenOutput>ExceptionResources.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
</EmbeddedResource>
```

However inside Solution Explorer I can see the following:

[image]

Of course it is not a big problem for the project, but I wanted to know how can I collapse by using DependentUpon as how I used to do.

Thank you in advance for your time, help and collaboration :)

Comment: **Related:** See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55788856/1497596) for how to nest (group) `.cs` files in a .NET Core project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ExceptionResources.es-ES.resx` is likely already an `EmbeddedResource` item so a `<Compile Update=…` on it will have no effect.

Instead, extend your `<EmbeddedResource Update=…`:

```
<EmbeddedResource Update="Resources\ExceptionResources.es-ES.resx">
  <DependentUpon>ExceptionResources.resx</DependentUpon>
  <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
  <LastGenOutput>ExceptionResources.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
</EmbeddedResource>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot @MartinUllrich, it works, all resx are collpased now. 
Best regards