# Visual studio 2017 : nesting files in a class library project

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

In web projects you have the option of nesting files

```
 + startup.cs
   +--startup.internals.cs
   +--startup.configuration.cs
```

Is there any way to achieve the same behavior in a class library project as well ?

**Updates : Partially solved**

Ok got it ,

You need to be aware of your files path.

for a structure like this (the files are at project level)

```
+-- myProject.csproj
   +-- startup.cs
   +-- startup.internals.cs
   +-- startup.configuration.cs
```

Then this is the configuration you are looking for.

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Update="startup.*.cs">
      <DependentUpon>startup.cs</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>
```

For a nested folder structure

```
+-- myProject.csproject
   +-- Folder_A
      +-- Folder_A1
         +-- startup.cs
         +-- startup.internals.cs
         +-- startup.configuration.cs
```

you need to get hold of the project path using the buildin $(ProjectDir) macro

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Update=" $(ProjectDir)\Folder_A\Folder_A1\startup.*.cs">
      <DependentUpon> $(ProjectDir)\Folder_A\Folder_A1\startup.cs</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Why do I say it is partially working, well because if I exit Visual and then open it again, for the 2nd type of structure, it will un-nest the files.

Some help anyone ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> To answer your **Updates : Partially solved**:

Something similar to [this issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/94671/csproj-dependentupon-is-ignored-for-subfolder-item.html).
`DependentUpon` is the correct element to use to achieve the nesting that you want.

But, your value cannot be expression that includes wildcards. It must be a single file that is under the same folder or a sub-folder. If your file exists in a sub-folder, you must specify the file via a relative path. So the content of your `ItemGroup` should be like this:

```
<Compile Include="Folder_A\Folder_A1\startup.cs" />
<Compile Include="Folder_A\Folder_A1\startup.configuration.cs">
  <DependentUpon>startup.cs</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="Folder_A\Folder_A1\startup.internals.cs">
  <DependentUpon>startup.cs</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

And after my check, I think you need to use the `Include` attribute instead of `Update` if you are building a .NET FX class library project.

**Update:**
The `Update` attribute is available only for .NET Core projects according to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/item-element-msbuild?view=vs-2019#attributes-and-elements).

And if in a .NET Core project, like what you indicated in a comment, maybe `Update` is more suitable:

```
<Compile Update="Folder_A\Folder_A1\startup.internals.cs">
  <DependentUpon>startup.cs</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

Comment: Not sure but for some reason it doesn't work for .NET core unless instead of Include I'm using Update .. 
  `<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Update="Folder_A\Folder_A1\startup.*.cs">
      <DependentUpon>startup.cs</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>`. Still favorite answer. Thank you for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can do this in your csproj file.

```
<Compile Include="startup.cs">
    <DependentUpon>startup.internals.xaml</DependentUpon>
    <DependentUpon>startup.configureation.xaml</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```